# XML to asp.net Input Form

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, webforms

I need to store records of different types in a generic record table. I want to store an xml string in a column of each record. This xml string should be converted into a question form based on what is specified by the xml. Example:

```
<Questionnaire Form> 
   <Textbox>
       <Label>Question</Label>
       <Answer>Answer To the Question</Answer>
   </Textbox>
   <Textbox>
       <Label>Question</Label>
       <Answer>Answer To the Question</Answer>
   </Textbox>
</Questionnaire Form>
```

When the question is answered it will just be saved back into the record by storing it into the entire xml string.

I have seen many examples of displaying data onto a form from xml ,but can't seem to find how you create components (like a textbox) from the xml, be able to edit the textbox and save it back in the xml. This might be very ambiguous ,but if someone should point me in the right direction or just show me how you would go by creating dynamic components from xml it will be a great help.

I am doing this in asp.net using vb.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality looks pretty straightforward. Here are some steps I would try:

1) Read your XML and parse data with standard .NET methods. The classes that should help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx
or
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

So after this step you will have all your information in some list of items. (You will probably need to create your own class to store necessary data).

2) Place some DIV or asp:Panel or something else to your aspx or ascx markup. Then on Page_Init add new textboxes programmatically. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx
Initilize them with default data. (You should add them doesn't matter if IsPostBack is true or false). Don't forget to assign IDs to your generated inputs, for example with a method like this:

```
private string MakeInputID(int objectID)
{
    return string.Format("input_{1}", objectID);
}
```

3) Then obviously you will have some button to submit the answers. Attach to its click handler and here you can access your textboxes by their IDs. You can find textboxes with the help of FindControl method of the DIV or Panel container, that I mentioned in the step 1). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx
You will need the same method MakeInputID to get ID of the control and pass it to the FindControl method.